# How to print a multiple characters given variable number times?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, variables, design-patterns

Suppose if I want to print ".|." for (2k+1) times. Below is my snippet of code. How to do that? It is throwing a syntax error.

```
for k in range(0,n/2):
        print('.|.' * (2k+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly multiply `k` by `2` using the `*` operator - you can't just write `2k`:

```
print('.|.' * (2 * k +1 ))
# Here ----------^
```

Comment: ohh .Thanks for that.